# Upload web app to Microsoft Server

Tags: php, upload, web-config, server

I have a local web app and now I want to upload it. I chose a server but now I'm confused what to do. ( The server is based in Windows). On the server I got a web.config and I have no idea if I should configure it or not.
If I try to acces my webApp an error appears:

https://gyazo.com/9aa22a51e9d73676f2bcac0cb6b642a2

And the web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <clear />
                     <add value="login.php" />

                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

It's a constraint declare a default document? I got a controller which function is redirect to the correct page properly. The web app language is PHP.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is php5 is installed on server?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem is I was working with Apache and now I should change the .htaccess to web.config. ( I think )